# How can I use .some() to find if an array of objects contains a specific property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, exists, any

I've an array containing objects, where every object represents a person that's going to a video theatre.
The objects contains properties such as Name, Age and Hobby.
If there is (atleast) one person younger than 18, the variable **censor** should be set to *true*.

My code below yields the value false, despite Tim being younger than 18.
Is it not possible to use .some() this way, or what am I doing wrong?

```
var persons = [
    {Name: "Joel", Age:25, Hobby:"Fishing"},
    {Name: "Michael", Age:31, Hobby:"Astronomy"},
    {Name: "Tim", Age:12, Hobby:"Video Games"},
]

var censor = persons.some((person) => {person.Age < 18})
console.log(censor) --> false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return in your callback that is why it is always `false`,

either use:

```
var censor = persons.some(person => person.Age < 18)
```

or

```
var censor = persons.some(person => {return person.Age < 18 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
var censor = persons.some((person) => person.Age < 18); // <-- no curly brackets for the predicate
```

instead of `{person.Age < 18}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the brackets.

```js
var persons = [
    {Name: "Joel", Age:25, Hobby:"Fishing"},
    {Name: "Michael", Age:31, Hobby:"Astronomy"},
    {Name: "Tim", Age:12, Hobby:"Video Games"},
]

var censor = persons.some((person) => person.Age < 18)
console.log(censor)
```

If you want to continue using brackets, then you need to add `return` to the statement:

```js
var censor = persons.some((person) => {
  return person.Age < 18
})
```